# Spring 3 doesn't fill @Value annotated fields with property values

Tags: spring, properties, code-injection

I want to fill some fields with the property values using Spring 3.1.1 but the fields always remain null.

Added to the applicationContext.xml

```
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

  <util:properties id="props" location="classpath:application.properties" />
```

application.properties:

```
myProp=value
```

java class:

```
  @Value("#{props[myProp]}")
  private String myField;
```

But on bean creation myField is not filled with "value" from the properties file but remains null.

Also tried (without success):

```
  @Value("#{props.myProp}")
  private String myField;
```

and

```
  @Value("#{myProp}")
  private String myField;
```

The application.properties file is found because I got an "file not found" after I moved it.

Here the stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/5A8i5gF8

What do I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared or configured your class which has myField class variable into applicationContext.xml?

Answer (score 0):

try with the char $ instead of #
example:

```
 @Value("${myProp}")
  private String myField;
```

Comment: Sadly, that didn't change the behaviour

Comment: the only other difference with a project i have then is that i use org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to load my properties example: `<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
 <property name="locations">
  <list>
   <value>classpath:mypath1/prop1.properties</value>
   <value>classpath:mypath2/prop2.properties</value>
  </list>
 </property>
 <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>` and this **before instantiating the class where the injection occurs**

Comment: you must be missing a `<context:annotation-config/>` as suggested by Biju then. if it doesn't solve the issue try to post your spring config files so we can look into them.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing `<context:component-scan/>` or `<context:annotation-config/>` in your application context - it registers a bean called `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` which actually processes the @Value tag. If it is not there, just add one of the two and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion..I still had that in my xml.. I posted the relevant parts of my applicationContext.xml which I should have done earlier

Comment: That is strange, I have a very similar setup as yours and it works well for me - can you please also show the definition of this bean(one in which you are injecting through `@Value` in the xml file)

Comment: I can confirm that adding either component-scan or annotation-config doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting new answer but in comments  code doesn't get formatted properly.

```
@Repository
@Qualifier(value = "myStrategy")
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {

    @Value("${prop1}")
    private String prop1;

    MyClass(){
        <prop1 is passed to a method to set a config.>
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://cxf.apache.org/core
      http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
      http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
      http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

    <context:annotation-config />   
    <context:component-scan base-package="my.base.package" /> 
    <util:properties id="props" location="classpath:application.properties" />


    ... <some beans (transactions, persistence, ws-endpoints) not used by the test class > ....

        <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging />
        </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus>

</beans>
```